# Running Locust in Docker Container ignores Host parameter

Tags: locust

I have the following compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  worker:
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"
    image: locustio/locust
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: --config=/mnt/locust/devndb.conf --users 1 --spawn-rate 1 --run-time 10s --host http://devndb-ci:8081 --headless -f /mnt/locust/rest/normId_by_external_identifier.py
```

When I run the container the --host argument is not evaluated in my locust file.
When I run the locust file directly without a container it works:

```
locust --headless --users 10 --spawn-rate 1 -H http://devndb-ci:8081 --run-time 10s -f rest/normId_by_external_identifier.py
```

Is this a bug in the locust docker image?

I am expecting the locust container to take the --host argument into account and build the REST URLs accordingly.

Comment: Is locust receiving the command correctly, or is the problem in docker/compose? Please check the process using ps and add it here. There was an issue not long ago that might be similar (but relating to k8s/helm), but I cant find it now…

Comment: It seems to me that the arguments are passed correctly, thanks for the hint!
                
00:00:06            /opt/venv/bin/python /opt/venv/bin/locust --config=/mnt/locust/devndb.conf --users 1 --spawn-rate 1 --run-time 100s --host http://devndb-ci:8081 --headless -f /mnt/locust/rest/normId_by_external_identifier.py 

Maybe the problem is relating to another issue like networking, proxy or firewall I have to check this.

Comment: That command is missing the `http://`-part of the host parameter though?

Comment: The http://-part was automatically removed when adding the comment here but it is actually present!

Comment: Ah. Yea, then you should probably check the things you mentioned. DNS is sometimes an issue too.